# Importar grandes bases de datos de excel a mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, excel

soy primerizo en mysql workbentch. Quiero importar 2 bases de datos para enlazarlas: la primera es de 26324 datos y la segunda de de más de 4 millones, sin embargo al momento de intentar hacerlo con el botón de mysql en excel me dice que no es posible y me arroja el siguiente error[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿alguien sabe cómo le ´puedo hacer?

Comment: Bastante extensa tu pregunta y sin saber estructura ni ejemplos mucho más. Intenta hacerlo por partes y "en caliente" para ver las posibles causas. Aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).

Comment: Has intentado guardar los archivos de Excel como CSV?

Comment: Saludos.  En relación a la imagen que compartes; mira que en **Default value**; prueba colocando sea *NULL*; adicionalmente, verifica que en cada celda existan valores válidos para el tipo de dato declarado y en el caso de número dentro del rango que soporta el tipo indicado.